# Running a drupal site using Minikube

Tags: kubernetes, drupal, drupal-8, minikube

I'm learning how to use Kubernetes by using Minikube and creating a Drupal site.

I was able to `minikube service` my drupal site and reach up to the "Set up Database" page and that's about it. It keeps telling me I need to insert the correct info. I checked my MYSQL pod and was able to `exec` and MySQL into my database.

I'm not sure what I'm missing? Is MYSQL pod not connected to my Drupal pod?

Here's my drupal-mysql.yaml file:

```html
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: drupal-mysql-service
spec:
  ports:
    - name: mysql
      port: 3306
      targetPort: 3306
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: drupal
  type: ClusterIP
---
apiVersion: apps/v1 # for versions before 1.9.0 use apps/v1beta2
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: drupal-mysql
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mysql
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mysql
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: mysql:5.7
          name: mysql
          env:
            # Use secret in real usage
            - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
              value: seto_password
            - name: MYSQL_DATABASE
              value: drupal_databases
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3306
              name: mysql
              protocol: TCP
          volumeMounts:
            - name: vol-drupal
              mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
              subPath: 'mysql'
      volumes:
        - name: vol-drupal
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: drupal-seto-mysql
```

Here's my drupal.yaml file:

```html
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: drupal
  labels:
    app: drupal
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: drupal
      tier: frontend
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: drupal
        tier: frontend
    spec:
      selector:
      initContainers:
        - name: init-sites-volume
          image: drupal:8.9.11
          command: ['/bin/bash', '-c']
          args:
            [
              'cp -r /var/www/html/sites/ /data/; chown www-data:www-data /data/ -R',
            ]
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /data
              name: vol-drupal
      containers:
        - image: drupal:8.9.11
          name: drupal
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /var/www/html/modules
              name: vol-drupal
              subPath: modules
            - mountPath: /var/www/html/profiles
              name: vol-drupal
              subPath: profiles
            - mountPath: /var/www/html/sites
              name: vol-drupal
              subPath: sites
            - mountPath: /var/www/html/themes
              name: vol-drupal
              subPath: themes
      volumes:
        - name: vol-drupal
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: drupal-seto
```

And Here's my drupal-service.yaml:

```html
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: drupal-service
  labels:
    app: drupal
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - name: web
      protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: drupal
```

Comment: What kind of information it is asking for?

Comment: What exact error are you getting ? Are you using specific tutorial for this setup ?  Have you seen this article - https://medium.com/containerum/how-to-easily-deploy-a-drupal-8-instance-on-kubernetes-b90acc7786b7 ? Can you change drupal service to LoadBalancer as in example in article? Have you tried access app using MinikubeIP:NodePort ? Also to connect backend with frontend you have to add extra label which will connect them - read more: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/connecting-frontend-backend/

Answer (score 0):

You need to connect between containers using IP address of containers or may be pods, but what is point of getting database in container, instead install mysql in host machine I have done it, checkout the guide

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Y4RJrk-cFw